# Post List<Model> from form in MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a need to be able to post back an unknown number of this model class:

```
public class UserRegisterModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string RepName { get; set; }

    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
}
```

in a `List<UserRegisterModel>` to a controller.

I need my view to have a form that can send back multiple instances of the model to the controller, so for example if my user wants to add 3 Reps, he can make 3 reps and give them each details and usernames and passwords, and send them all back at once in a List.

I have this starting point for my view code:

```
@model List<PicsWebApp.Models.UserRegisterModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "NewRep";
}

<h2>NewRep</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("NewRep", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "fieldform", @class = "form" }))
{
}
```

Can anybody show me the correct way of accomplishing this? I know I need javascript in order to dynamically add more form elements if the user clicks "add new rep" so this is mainly about the C#.

Comment: Take a look, http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make sure the properties' ID's conform to the standard set (I used the link from Felipe's comment when I was doing this).  I did this before, where a table row would get added when the user click a button.  I found the best way is to add an entry before the page gets rendered, then taking the HTML for that, and using it in your jquery.

Here's a function I've used:

```
$("#nameAdd").click(function (e) {
   var index = $("#nameTable tr").length - 1;
   e.preventDefault();
   var newItem = $("<tr> \
                  <td> \
                    <span id='Names_" + index + "__FullName' /> \
                  </td> \
                  <td> \
                    <input class='table-editor-small update-name' id='Names_" + index + "__FirstName' name='Names[" + index + "].FirstName' type='text' value='' /> \
                  </td> \
                  <td> \
                    <input class='table-editor-small update-name' id='Names_" + index + "__MiddleName' name='Names[" + index + "].MiddleName' type='text' value='' /> \
                  </td> \
                  <td> \
                    <input class='table-editor-small update-name' data-val='true' data-val-required='Person Last Name Required' id='Names_" + index + "__LastName' name='Names[" + index + "].LastName' type='text' value='' /> \
                  </td> \
                  <td class='center'> \
                    <input data-group='nameRadios' id='Names_" + index + "__IsPrimary' name='Names[" + index + "].IsPrimary' type='radio' value='True' /> \
                  </td> \
                  <td class='center'> \
                    <input data-val='true' data-val-required='The Delete? field is required.' id='Names_" + index + "__ToDelete' name='Names[" + index + "].ToDelete' type='checkbox' value='true' /> \
                    <input name='Names[" + index + "].ToDelete' type='hidden' value='false' /> \
                  </td> \
                </tr>");
    $("#nameTable").append(newItem);
}
```

again, the HTML to add is straight from an item that had been rendered by the view, i just swapped in the `index`

Comment: it's quite hard to decipher what you've done there and relate it to my own task haha

Comment: Sorry, I hope that was able to offer you some guidance